# depends_on erroring out, static list expression is required

Tags: terraform

So, I have a block of code-

```
resource "bigip_ltm_virtual_server" "agent_vip" {
  depends_on                 = [var.use_traefik ? bigip_ltm_pool.agent_lb_443_pool : bigip_ltm_pool.agent_lb_30443_pool, null_resource.sync_check]
  description                = "${var.cluster_name}.${var.domain}_443"
  destination                = "${var.agent_f5_ip_address}"
  ip_protocol                = "tcp"
  name                       = "/Common/${var.cluster_name}.${var.domain}_443"
  pool                       = var.use_traefik ? "/Common/${var.cluster_name}-lbaas-agent_lb-443-pool" : "/Common/${var.cluster_name}-lbaas-agent_lb-30443-pool"
  port                       = 443
  profiles                   = ["/Common/tcp"]
  source_address_translation = "automap"
  translate_address          = "enabled"
  translate_port             = "enabled"
}
```

when I run terraform apply it errors out saying -

```
Error: Invalid expression

  on main.tf line 193, in resource "bigip_ltm_virtual_server" "agent_vip":
 193:   depends_on                 = var.use_traefik ? [bigip_ltm_pool.agent_lb_443_pool, null_resource.sync_check] : [bigip_ltm_pool.agent_lb_30443_pool, null_resource.sync_check]

A static list expression is required.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit dependencies are static references, not arbitrary expressions.

```
depends_on = [
  bigip_ltm_pool.agent_lb_443_pool,
  bigip_ltm_pool.agent_lb_30443_pool,
  null_resource.sync_check,
]
```

What you need to do here is listing the exhaustive set of resources that this resource depends on. That means that Terraform will wait until all three of these complete before taking actions for `bigip_ltm_virtual_server.agent_vip`, which might be more dependencies than strictly necessary but those additional dependencies shouldn't cause any practical problems because this dependency graph is *conservative*, meaning that it has all of the dependencies that are needed *and more*, rather than fewer than needed.

The idiomatic way to express this in Terraform is to use implicit dependencies via references wherever possible. In this case, you can use references within the `pool` argument to imply the dependency on the two pools:

```
resource "bigip_ltm_virtual_server" "agent_vip" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.sync_check]

  description                = "${var.cluster_name}.${var.domain}_443"
  destination                = var.agent_f5_ip_address
  ip_protocol                = "tcp"
  name                       = "/Common/${var.cluster_name}.${var.domain}_443"
  pool                       = var.use_traefik ? bigip_ltm_pool.agent_lb_443_pool.name : bigip_ltm_pool.agent_lb_30443_pool.name
  port                       = 443
  profiles                   = ["/Common/tcp"]
  source_address_translation = "automap"
  translate_address          = "enabled"
  translate_port             = "enabled"
}
```

Because the `pool` argument refers to both `bigip_ltm_pool.agent_lb_443_pool` and `bigip_ltm_pool.agent_lb_30443_pool`, Terraform can infer those dependencies automatically. Therefore only `null_resource.sync_check` must appear in `depends_on`, presumably because that resource has some sort of side-effect that can't be described as data flow between resources.